# How can I force Excel to recalculate after a UDF macro error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I created a bug in a user-defined function that is called from a large number of cells on many tables in an Excel workbook (not the way I would design it, I just "inherited" it).

But now, I can't seem to get rid of the `#VALUE` errors in the cells referencing this VBA function.

Tried so far:

- Calculation menu, "Calculate Sheet"
- Saving, re-opening (this workbook is set to calculate before saving)
- Setting the calculation mode to Manual and back again to Automatic
- ActiveSheet.Calculate
- Application.Calculate
- Application.CalculateFull

The only thing that seems to work is editing each cell and just hitting Enter to reset each formula, or overwriting the formulas via copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out as I was typing the question:

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Answer (score -1):

There must be a better solution but you can simulate editing the cell by doing a replace of = with = across the whole tab.